# IE - using 100% height within table-row

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I'm using css tables where the last table row has height 100% - to fill up the remaining height.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yKPq3/15/)

This works for me cross-browser (Including IE).

However, if I then add in the last table-row some divs with fixed height (this is dynamic content - I don't know how many of them there are) where the last div has height:100% -  in order to fill up the last table-row. - like this:

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/yKPq3/1/) -

this now doesn't work in IE (Even IE10)

What must I do to make this work in IE ?

(**Edit**: As correctly pointer out in the comments: It doesn't work in any browser - although in Chrome and firefox it *looks* like it works - the height:100% on the last div of the third row wasn't filling up the remaining height but rather taking up the complete height of row3...

So I attempted using table rows for row 3:- [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yKPq3/14/)... Now *this* works in other browsers, but still doesn't work in IE!)

### Markup

```
<div class="table">
    <div class="row row1">row1</div>
    <div class="row row2">row2</div>
    <div class="row row3">
        <div class="row3a">row3a</div>
        <div class="row3b">row3b</div>
        <div class="row3c">row3c</div> <!-- in IE this doesn't fill the last row -->
    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.table
{
    display: table;
    width: 600px;
    height: 300px;
}
.row
{
    display: table-row;
}
.row1
{
    height: 50px;
    background: pink;
}
.row2
{
    height: 100px;
    background: orange;
}
.row3
{
    height: 100%;
    background: yellow;
}
.row3a
{
    height: 30px;
    background: purple;
}
.row3b
{
    height: 60px;
    background: aqua;
}
.row3c
{
    height: 100%;
    background: brown;
}
```

Comment: use ids for row1, row2, and row3 specific rules.

Comment: @ArunAravind I'm doing that on purpose to show different colors for each element so that you can see what's happening

Comment: I've always found that if you want cross-browser compatibility with CSS tables, you should actually simulate an entire table. That is, use nested divs three levels deep with `display:table`, `display:table-row` and `display:table-cell` respectively.

Comment: are you allowed to add another wrapper inside `row3`? (between the row and the actual content)

Comment: @avrahamcool - yes, although I'd *prefer* not to.

Comment: But how can you set height = 100% to fill the remaining portion. It won't work as expected. In chrome the last row (row3c) overflows. In IE it won't work. IE gives the perfect result as per your code.

Comment: Since you render it as table-row you don't need to write any specific code to fill the container with the last row.

Comment: Remove your height: 100% from row3c and run it. This gives you the result you are trying for. Exact same result as in IE

Comment: In your first Fiddle, why add height to `.row3`? You set a height to the table, the first and the second row. So even without the height, it fills up the remaining space, check [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/yKPq3/4/). With that knowledge, applying it to your second fiddle, this comes out: [**click**](http://jsfiddle.net/yKPq3/5/). You can see that `.row3` doesn't overflow. However, `.row3c` doesn't fill up the space. Why don't you want them to be displayed as a table??

Comment: @ArunAravind true, I didn't notice that it overflowed in other browsers, but if I remove the 100% - it doesn't fill up the remaining height of my third row

Comment: @LinkinTED - I created an over-simplified fiddle. To use tables within tables will be quite a lot of work (I think) - but If that's the only way - then I'll accept that too. (I edited my question to reflect this too)

Comment: @Danield: See my edit below. set percentage heights for row3a, row3b, and row3c

Comment: @Danield I've submitted a IE8+ solution, + a hidden jem..

Answer (score 3):

### Pure CSS, Cross-Browser Solution, Without using CSS Table Layout.

I actually recomend you to **USE** the CSS table layout if you can. (I don't know why you don't want it in your rows, its perfectly fine.)
OR the `flexbox` layout, although it's not properly implemented yet in all browsers..
--I just read in the comments that it didn't worked for you in IE, well: my solution does.. even with IE8.

<kbd>[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/ZXgDm/1/)</kbd>

**HTML:** I'm using the extra wrapper I mentioned in the comment.

```
<div class="table">
    <div class="row1">row1</div>
    <div class="row2">row2</div>
    <div class="row3">
        <div class="Wrapper">
            <div class="row3a">row3a</div>
            <div class="row3b">row3b</div>
            <div class="row3c">row3c</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:** (most of it if for the backgrounds)

```
.table
{
    width: 600px;
    height: 900px;
}
.row1
{
    height: 50px;
    background: pink;
}
.row2
{
    height: 100px;
    background: orange;
}
.row3
{
    background: yellow;
    position: relative;
}

.row3a
{
    height: 30px;
    background: purple;
}
.row3b
{
    height: 60px;
    background: aqua;
}
.row3c
{
    background: brown;
}

.Wrapper
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.table:before, .Wrapper:before
{
    content: '';
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
}

.row3:after, .row3c:after
{
    content: '';
    display: block;
    clear: left;
}
```

Comment: The last row doesn't fill 100% of the remaining height of the table.

Comment: @BernardV yes it does. (look at the table definition in the CSS)

Comment: @avrahamcool: My bad, it breaks only with table { height: 100%; } which is  what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: @BernardV again.. you are mistaking. take a look at this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZXgDm/52/).

Comment: To the one who downvoted, care to share your opinion on why?

Answer (score 0):

IE gives you the perfect result you wanted. You are rendering it as table-row. You don't need to set specific height to the last row for it to fill the remaining space.

You are actually doing it wrong by setting height to 100%; 
Here 100% means the actual height of row3 and chrome renders it as you have written.

i.e row3c overflows its parent row3.

since you specified pixel heights for the remaining rows it won't fill. You need to specify
percentage heights for all ( row3a -> height: 20%, row3b -> height: 30%, row3c -> height: 50%)

it will work

Comment: But I want my third row to contain elements of fixed height and the last element to fill the remaining height

Comment: In such a situation the best thing you could do is avoid tables. Style div elements to get the appearence of a grid. Never ever use HTML tables for page layout. Only use them for tabular content. Tables takes off the flexibility in design. You can make your own component and reuse them whenever you want. Spend some time and that will help you in future.

Comment: The fix i mentioned above does not work in IE since IE have problems with rendering tables. They haven't fixed the issue till IE 10. so go for alternatives. You can make pure css grids without using tables or display: table.

Answer (score 0):

You are giving height to table as 300px,  Here is fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/yKPq3/11/  `and assuming you want table to be filled 300px, you need to change .row3 to height:150px and .row3c to height:60px`

Comment: Thanks, but my content is dynamic. I don't know how many divs there will be. What I need is the *last* element to fill the remaining height